# The same as in mysqli but in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

im ave a mysqli code and run good.

```
mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE `settings`
SET value = (CASE
WHEN name = 'address_web' THEN '".$_POST['address']."'
WHEN name = 'name_web' THEN '".$_POST['webname']."'
end)
WHERE name IN (
'address_web','name_web'
)");
```

I would like to know how I could have the same but in PDO

Thanks you for all ;-)

---

ok thanks you do not need an answer and I managed to do it

greetings to all

```
$pdo = db();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `settings`
SET value = (CASE
    WHEN name = 'address_web' THEN '".$testa."'
    WHEN name = 'name_web' THEN '".$testb."'
    end)
    WHERE name IN (
    'address_web','logo'
    )");
$stmt->bindValue("ss"); 
$stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: That's why people spend thousands of hours [writing documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: That is **not** correct. Please read more about PDO https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: I'm curious how that works when [`bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) takes a minimum of two parameters...

Comment: Thanks for your comments,
but I do not know much in PDO I just started
but this solution works perfectly to what I want

thanks to all